# Spring MVC RestTemplate POST using JSON

Tags: json, spring, rest

I have a Spring MVC Rest Controller that simply adds a customer record. My Rest Service passes around JSON and works fine when I call it from a web client or a test bed like Soap-UI. However, when I try to POST using RestTemplate I get a JacksonMappingException: Can not construct instance of CustomerObject, problem: no suitable creator method found.

It's clearly something to do with the way I am creating the JSON request so to add some meat to the bones here is what I'm doing:

My Test posts using RestTemplate

```
 @Test
 public void postCustomerIntegrationTest() throws Exception{

    String JSONInput = ("{" +
          "  \"firstName\": \"Anouska\"," +
          "  \"lastName\": \"Williams\"," +
          "  \"email\": \"Anouska@place.com\"," +
          "  \"cardBin1\": 123456768," +
          "  \"cardBin2\": 123456789," +
          "  \"language\": \"Spanish\"," +
          "  \"country\": \"Mexico\"," +
          "  \"product\": \"shit\"," +
          "  \"telephoneNumber\": 447869995262," +
          "  \"termsAndConditions\": \"true\"" +
          "}");

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  HttpEntity request= new HttpEntity(JSONInput, headers);

Registration output = restTemplate.postForObject(BASE_URL, request, CustomerObject.class);

assertNotNull("no person",output);
assertNotNull(output.getId());
assertEquals("Bob", output.getFirstName());

}
```

My RestTemplate is wired through Spring as follows:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
<property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

The test JSON I'm using here is the same as the test JSON I use in Soap-UI. Having debuged the code it looks like it is treating my JSON as a String and Jackson is trying to convert the entire thing because it can't find an assiciated field (which of course it can't).

I guess I need to know how to pass JSON to my RestTemplate in such a way that the request will be picked up in the correct JSON format. I've spent all morning trying to find an example and can't find one anywhere.

Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem, last parameter should be class of response

```
Registration output = restTemplate.postForObject(BASE_URL, request, Registration.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to post josn:

```
CustomerObject object = template.postForObject(
            BASE_URL, request, CustomerObject.class);
```

And CustomerObject class must have fields: firstName, lastName...